# Error when compiling, error in array

Tags: c++, arrays, compilation

> float premios[20]={500.00, 700.00, 800.00, 900.00, 1200.00, 1500.00, 1800.00, 2000.00, 2100.00, 2300.00, 2800.00, 3000.00, 3200.00, 3500.00, 4000.00, 10,000.00, 100,000.00, 200,000.00, 500,000.00, 1,000,000.00 };

Look at the code, when i try to compile it, it gives me the error "[Error] too many initializers for 'float [20]' ", it has exactly 20 values, tried to correct it by setting it to 21 values but it didnt work. Then i set the array to an empty array and it worked, can anybody explain me why did it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "," between each value count as a value. so I think 1,000,000.00 for example count as 3 values. `eg. [1, 0, 0]`

I believe you were trying to do 1000000.00 instead of 1,000,000.00

Answer (score 4):

Your initializer contains 26 elements.

Adds: Using > `float premios[] = ...` does not mean it's an empty array -- it means the number of elements in the array is deduced from the initializer, so it will turn out a float[26].

Comment: why 26? do the dots count as elements?

Comment: @PacoMeraz The commas separate the elements.  There are 25 commas, hence 26 elements.